# viewPanel.getSelectedIds returns 0

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a button which should change the value of a field on the selected documents from a viewpanel. But whatever I do, I also switched the columns where the checkbox was, I always get 0 ids.

Here is my viewPanel:

```
<xp:viewPanel rows="30" id="viewPanel1" pageName="/Account.xsp" var="rowData">
    <xp:this.facets>
        <xp:pager partialRefresh="true"
                layout="FirstImage PreviousImage SeparatorPage Group NextImage LastImage"
                xp:key="headerPager" id="pager1" alwaysCalculateLast="true">
        </xp:pager>
    </xp:this.facets>
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="Konten\Fehler">
        <xp:this.search><![CDATA[#{javascript:return viewScope.get( "searchString" );}]]></xp:this.search>
        </xp:dominoView>
    </xp:this.data>

    <xp:viewColumn id="viewColumn10" columnName="$errCodes">
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:viewColumnHeader xp:key="header" id="viewColumnHeader10" value="Fehler">
            </xp:viewColumnHeader>
        </xp:this.facets>
    </xp:viewColumn>
    <xp:viewColumn id="viewColumn9" styleClass="total">
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:viewColumnHeader xp:key="header" id="viewColumnHeader9">
            </xp:viewColumnHeader>
        </xp:this.facets>
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:if( rowData.isCategory() )
{
    return rowData.getColumnValue( "$11" )
}}]]></xp:this.value>
        <xp:this.converter>
            <xp:convertNumber type="number" integerOnly="true">
            </xp:convertNumber>
        </xp:this.converter>
    </xp:viewColumn>
    <xp:viewColumn id="viewColumn8" columnName="accountnumber" displayAs="link">
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:viewColumnHeader xp:key="header" id="viewColumnHeader8" value="Konto" sortable="true">
            </xp:viewColumnHeader>
        </xp:this.facets>
    </xp:viewColumn>
    <xp:viewColumn columnName="iban" id="viewColumn1" showCheckbox="true">
        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="IBAN" id="viewColumnHeader1" sortable="true">
        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
    </xp:viewColumn>
    <xp:viewColumn columnName="accounttype" id="viewColumn2">
        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Typ" id="viewColumnHeader2">
        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
    </xp:viewColumn>
    <xp:viewColumn id="viewColumn7" columnName="$info">
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:viewColumnHeader xp:key="header" id="viewColumnHeader7" value="Fehlermeldung" sortable="true">
            </xp:viewColumnHeader>
        </xp:this.facets>
    </xp:viewColumn>
</xp:viewPanel>
```

and the button

```
<xp:button value="Ausblenden" id="button1" styleClass="btn-info">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="norefresh">
        <xp:this.action>
            <![CDATA[#{javascript:
            var viewPanel = getComponent( "viewPanel1" );
            var docIDArray = viewPanel.getSelectedIds();
            for( i=0; i < docIDArray.length; i++ )
            {
                var docId = docIDArray[i];
                var doc:NotesDocument = database.getDocumentByID( docId );
                doc.replaceItemValue( "$shErr", 0 );
                doc.save();
            }
        }]]>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

but somehow getSelectedIds returns no id at all.
Any ideas? Thanks for your time!

Comment: You posted the button action code but not the whole button code. Where's the rest?

Comment: edited the post, so now all the code is available

Comment: When you say you get 0 ids you mean an empty array? If you add `println('selected ids: ' + docIDArray);` after the `docIDArray` assignment does the domino console at output anything?

Comment: Your button code looks good.  Try moving the showCheckbox="true" property to the first column in the view

Answer (score 0):

If you try the below, do you get anything from unidArray?

```
 var unidArray = new Array();
                        for(i=0; i < docIDArray.length; i++) {
                       var unid=database.getDocumentByID(docIDArray[i]).getUniversalID();
                          unidArray.push(unid);
                        }
```